# Transplant in combination with stem cell transplant

Tags: immunosuppressant, organ-transplant, stem-cells

I was wondering, if you transplant a kidney from person A to person B and combine it with a stem cell transplant, would you then need no/less immunosuppressive drugs? Since you would have an antibody match? It's just a hypothetical, I know in reality it would be very challenging. This is no homework question or whatsoever. I was watching a lecture on immunosuppressive therapy and this came to mind.
I'm just a simple Clinical Technology student with a immunology test coming Monday :)